# GoogleMaps - App Crash when init GMSMapView

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, swiftui, google-maps-sdk-ios

When I try to initialize the map, app crashed. I have same issue in UIkit.
I try clean pods, update pod and clean project. Last week it was working correctly, no joke

iOS: 16.2
iPhone: 14 plus
GoogleMaps 7.4.0

Code

```
            func makeUIView(context: Context) -> GMSMapView {
                let camera: GMSCameraPosition = .init(latitude: currentLocation.latitude, longitude: currentLocation.longitude, zoom: 16.0)
        
 crash here --> let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.zero, camera: camera)
                mapView.delegate = context.coordinator
                mapView.isMyLocationEnabled = true
                context.coordinator.mapView = mapView
        
                self.updateCircle(mapView: mapView)
        
                return mapView
            }
```

Report file

```
Date/Time:           2024-02-27 20:42:46.7377 -0600
Launch Time:         2024-02-27 20:36:28.3196 -0600
OS Version:          macOS 13.4.1
Release Type:        User

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  17

Thread 0::  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   ???                                    0x1491f5f50 ???
1   ???                                    0x1491f5da0 ???
2   app-name                               0x105075b60 __InstrumentSessionWithConfigurationDelegateDelegateQueue_block_invoke + 48
3   app-name                               0x11311ee34 -[GMSx_GTMSessionFetcher createSessionWithDelegate:sessionIdentifier:] + 569
4   app-name                               0x11311dedb -[GMSx_GTMSessionFetcher beginFetchMayDelay:mayAuthorize:mayDecorate:] + 2019
5   app-name                               0x1130de6b0 GMSAllSDKCheckForUpdatesImpl + 281
6   libdispatch.dylib                      0x1611fef5b _dispatch_client_callout + 8
7   libdispatch.dylib                      0x1612005b5 _dispatch_once_callout + 66
8   app-name                               0x1130387eb -[GMSServices initWithDisplayLink:resourceCache:clearcutClient:dataURL:cachesURL:options:] + 3558
9   app-name                               0x11301844f invocation function for block in CompleteInit(GMSAsyncInitServices*) + 241
10  app-name                               0x1130181e3 CompleteInit(GMSAsyncInitServices*) + 345
11  app-name                               0x11301825b -[GMSAsyncInitServices services] + 67
12  app-name                               0x11303758d +[GMSServices sharedServicesSync] + 136
13  app-name                               0x113023c89 -[GMSMapView initWithFrame:] + 40
14  app-name                               0x104d79b6d @nonobjc GMSMapView.init(frame:) + 61
15  app-name                               0x104d76f2a GMSMapView.__allocating_init(frame:) + 74
16  app-name                               0x10b442d26 AddressMapKit.makeUIView(context:) + 278 (AddressMapKit.swift:27)
17  app-name                               0x10b443299 protocol witness for UIViewRepresentable.makeUIView(context:) in conformance AddressMapKit + 73
```

Answer (score 1):

- check, if `let camera: GMSCameraPosition` has correct position, put static valid data for latitude and longitude and check, if it works now
- ensure that the Google Maps SDK is properly initialized in your `AppDelegate` with your API key before this view tries to use it.
- the line `mapView.isMyLocationEnabled = true` attempts to access the device's location. Make sure you have requested and been granted location permissions in your Info.plist file (`NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` for foreground access).

Comment: Camera has correct position and APIKey is correct.
Issue is in 
´let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.zero, camera: camera)´

Answer (score 0):

I have a update.
we saw that it was a problem with metal

---

If i turn off metal renderer, app is ok
GMSServices.setMetalRendererEnabled(false)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).